# Record limitation in pandas dataframe when importing from a csv file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, record

I am using Python 3.5.2 and Pandas based on Anaconda 4.2.0 (64bit, Windows 10) and want to import a csv file with 74 columns and ~51000 records, the size of the file is ~ 42.9MB on disk:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('MyCSVFile',dtype=str,delimiter=',',skipinitalspace=True, quotechar='"'

This code works fine also for additional operations to convert the strings into the desired data types. But for some strange reasons there seems to be a limitation in the total number of records. The length of the data frame shows only 39812 records, ie. not the full content of the csv file has been imported.
Is there a limitation in the maximum number of records to be imported into a pandas dataframe ?

Thank you for a hint.

Comment: If there is a limit, it's certainly not that small. There's either an error with your code or with the file. Hard to tell without seeing the data (at least in part).

Comment: I would suggest you to compare the last line in the CSV file with the last row in the DF: `print(df.iloc[-1])` - this way you'll see whether all rows have been parsed or not

Comment: Well, found the bug. Painful! But thanks anyway.